# JQuery Ajax: POST request send as GET

Tags: jquery, ajax

For some reason the following request is send as a GET request and not POST. However if I change the url slightly the request will be a POST. I hope someone can explain to me what im doing wrong.

```
$("#sendMessageForm").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/conversation/createmessage",
                data: $(this).serialize() + "&q={{ conversation_id }}",
                method: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    console.log('success');
                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.log("error")
                    console.log(data)
                }
            });
        });
```

[image: Request is send as GET]
When changing the URL:

[image: request send as post]

Comment: check the variable in the backed whether it revives as parameter values of value from request  because if u send data in data key in ajax then you need to get value from request..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hypothesis,

It is getting internally redirected to "en" language specific url.

Url starting with "/" would ideally take you to domain root but in the network log it is "/en/api/conversation/createmessage".

Options:

1. Remove internal redirection (To verify my hypothesis)
2. Directly put language prefix as part of url "/en/api/conversation/createmessage"
3. You can also check in some rest client, you should see the redirection response.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing data as a query string which you need to avoid. Pass data from ajax as below:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/conversation/createmessage",
            data: {
               'formData': $(this).serialize()                 
               'q': {{ conversation_id }} 
            },
            method: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                console.log('success');
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log("error")
                console.log(data)
            }
        });
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you are using POST method for form submission and passing data as a query string which is making an error. Correct that as below :

```
     // where data is an array of your input values and param 
    //can be a extra param you want to send or even a function (conversation_id in this case)
           __Ajax_call(data,url,param) {

                return  $.ajax({
                                url: url,
                                method: "POST",
                                data: {
                                data:data, q: param
                                     }
                            })
                 }
```

And then:

```
         $("#sendMessageForm").submit(function(e){
             var data = {
                        name: $("#id").value(),
                        ..............
                        }
             var param = conversation_id;
                     __Ajax_call(data,url,param)
                        .done(function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        }).fail(function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        })
                       e.preventDefault();
                    });
```

Hope it helps